# Search and delete files owned by selected user through batch

Tags: batch-file

My objective is:
- Find files owned by selected user
- Delete them

My current code:

```
@echo off
for /f %%f in ('dir /b /s') do call :delete_file %%f


GOTO :eof

:delete_file
(
   set var=%1
   dir /q %var%| find "\User"
)
```

I'm looping all files in current directory, then i'm calling :delete_file with parameter %%f (file path), then in :delete_file i'm setting var to first received parameter (%1 - file path). And now, i'm parsing again file (with /q paramter - to output Owner) in search of owner.
My question is, how to set output of:

```
dir /q %var%| find "\User"
```

To the variable? If output is null, then file is not owned by selected user, otherwise i can delete this file. But how to check this?

Answer (score 0):

This should echo the del command for files matching your text
If you are happy with it then remove the `echo` keyword and run it for real.

I also made the text compare case insensitive.

```
@echo off
for /f %%f in ('dir /b /s /a-d') do (
   dir /q "%%f"| find /v ":\" |find /i "%computername%\User">nul && echo del "%%f"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "skip=3 tokens=6*" %%a in ('dir /S /Q /A-D') do (
   set "owner=%%a"
   if "!owner:%COMPUTERNAME%\User=!" neq "!owner!" ECHO del "%%b"
)
```

Perhaps you need to adjust the `tokens=6*` part if the output of your `dir /Q` command is not equal to mine (I use Spanish version)...